# IIS removes If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since headers

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, http-headers, etag

I have an ASHX handler or an ASPX page (the problem happens in both cases).
The web client sends a request containing If-None-Match and/or If-Modified-Since headers but  context.Request.Headers.Get("If-None-Match") or  context.Request.Headers.Get("If-Modified-Since") is null in the handler.

The same script works in my local development machine but it doesn't work in the online machine (both are running IIS7 on Win 2008, .NET 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

You may use 3rd-party module to create duplicates of those headers before apsx page is executed.
For example with Helicon Ape (http://www.helicontech.com/ape) these rules may do the trick:

```
SetEnvIf If-None-Match (.*) e-if-none-match=$1
SetEnvIf If-Modified-Since (.*) e-if-modified-since=$1

RequestHeader set My-If-None-Match %{e-if-none-match}e
RequestHeader set My-If-Modified-Since %{e-if-modified-since}e
```

Basically they get the headers and set the new ones with My- prefix. This will work only if IIS doesn’t remove headers before Ape.

Comment: Thanks, but any idea why does IIS remove those headers?

Comment: I noticed that the header is available when I access the handler from the local computer, but IIS removes it when I access the handler from a remote computer.

Also I tried to create a IHttpModule, but it doesn't help because the header has been already removed before HttpApplication.BeginRequest is called.

Comment: I suggest you to ask on iis.net forums. I honestly don’t know why IIS removes those headers. It’s quite possible though, because I know for sure that IIS'es low-level driver adds Content-Length header after all the modules. The same thing with Server header.